# Record Linkage with multiple datasets

Tags: matching, record-linkage, textmatching

## The problem

**fastLink** and **RecordLinkage** packages do extremely well in matching records (rows) from database A to database B and vice-versa. The developers are working on extending from matching only 2 databases to multiple databases.

A simple example of both I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451607/r-record-linkage-problem-with-all-fields-combined-in-1-column?noredirect=1#comment95873138_54451607).

In the meantime, how would we go about matching multiple data frames? For example, I have multiple medical records of patients from clinic A, B, C, D, E, F, and I want to merge them into a single one.

## A reproducible example:

```
dfA <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar", "Nemo", "Simba", "Belle", "Nala", 
"Jasmine"), lname = c("Evil", "Water", "King", "Beauty", "Princess", 
"Princess"), gender = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), dob = c(1987, 
2000, 2011, 1989, 1970, 1989), city = c("Arabtown", "Atlantic", 
"Sahara", "Nice", "Sahara", "Arabtown")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dfB <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar Jr", "Nemo", "Simba", "Belle", 
"Nala", "Jasmine"), lname = c("Evil", "Waterson", "King", "Beauty", 
"Princess", "Princess of Arabtown"), gender = c("M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F"), dob = c(NA, 2000, 2011, NA, NA, 1989), city = c("Arabtown", 
"Atlantica", "Sahara", "Nice-France", "Sahara", "Arabia")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dfC <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar Jr", "Fishy", "Lion", "Belle", 
"Sarabi", "Jasmine"), lname = c("Evil", "Waterpal", "King", "Beauty", 
"Queen", NA), gender = c("M", "M", NA, "F", "F", "F"), dob = c(NA, 
2000, 2011, NA, 1940, 1989), city = c("Arabia", NA, "Sahara", 
"France", "Sahara", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
dfD <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar Jr", "Nemo", "Simba", "Belle", 
"Sarabi", "Jasmine"), lname = c("Evil", "Waterson", "King", "Beast", 
"Queen", "Evil"), gender = c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M"), dob = c(NA, 
2000, 2011, 1989, NA, 1989), city = c("Arabtown", "Atlantica", 
"Sahara", NA, "Sahara", "Arabtown")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
dfE <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar Jr", "Nemo", "Simba", "Belle", 
"Nala", "Aladdin"), lname = c("Evil", "Pateron", NA, "Gaston", 
NA, "Streetrat"), gender = c("M", NA, "M", "F", "F", "M"), dob = c(1987, 
NA, NA, NA, 1970, 1989), city = c("Arabtown", "Atlantica", "Sahara", 
"France", "Sahara", "Arabia")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
dfF <- 
structure(list(fname = c("Jafar Jr", "Nemo", "Simba", "Belle", 
"Nala", "Al"), lname = c("Evil", "Waterson", "Dead", "Beauty", 
"Princess", "Streetrat"), gender = c("M", "M", NA, "F", "F", 
"M"), dob = c(1987, 2000, 2011, NA, NA, 1989), city = c("Arabia", 
"Atlantic", "Sahara", "Nice-France", "Sahara", "Arabia")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Expected result :

In the end I want unique identified records :

```
1 Jafar   Evil     M       1987 Arabtown
2 Nemo    Water    M       2000 Atlantic
3 Simba   King     M       2011 Sahara  
4 Belle   Beauty   F       1989 Nice    
5 Nala    Princess F       1970 Sahara  
6 Jasmine Princess F       1989 Arabtown
7 Sarabi   Queen    F       1940 Sahara
8 Aladdin  Streetrat M       1989 Arabia
```

Even if the result isn't as clean as above, it's alright. The goal is to find a unified record from all 6 records and belong to the same entity.
Both **fastLink** & **RecordLinkage** take care of deduping (removing duplicates).

How can I develop an approach to deal with more than two databases in this scenario?